# CHECK constraint not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, check-constraint

I have to create a check constraint on the table based on the below condition.

**1. If ColumnX=1 then ColumnY should not be NULL**

**2. If ColumnX<>1 then ColumnY can be NULL**

I tried below and seems to be not checking the value.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_1] 

CHECK  (ColumnX<>1 OR(ColumnX=1 AND (ISNULL(ColumnY,0) <> 0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_1]
GO
```

Not sure whether the logic in the constraint is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
CHECK ( ColumnX <> 1 OR (ColumnX = 1 AND ColumnY is not null) )
```

If `ColumnX` can be `NULL`, you might want:

```
CHECK ( ColumnX <> 1 OR ColumnX is null OR (ColumnX = 1 AND ColumnY is not null) )
```

Comment: This `CHECK ( ColumnX <> 1 OR (ColumnX = 1 AND ColumnY is not null) )` is fine. I am not sure why my appoach is not working by checking ISNULL with 0

Answer (score 0):

```
ColumnX != 1 or ColumnY is not null
```